# Javascript / Node.js ping ip addresses on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Javascript and node.js, but is this possible?

I want to put marker locations of some locations using Google Maps Javascript API, then I want to ping each ip addresses associated with the locations.  If they're up, show Green marker, else, show Red marker.  If this is possible, can someone point me toward the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NPM ping package :

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/ping][1]

Here an example:

```
var ping = require('ping');

var hosts = ['192.168.1.1', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
hosts.forEach(function(host){
   ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive){
        if(isAlive){
           makeMArkerGreen()
          }else {MakkeMarkerRed()}
           });
          });
```

Comment: Thank you.  So I want to have a constant ping going on these ip addresses, not just one time.  What would be the best solution?  Secondly, I have a CSV with ip addresses, how would I read that line by line so it pings each ip and displays the proper marker color?

Comment: Right now, I'm adding each locations manually, but it would be nicer if I can read it from csv